# Best way to poke or expect a vector port

Tags: chisel

If I need to test a module:

```
class myModule extends Module{
  val io = IO( 
    new Bundle{
      val In = Input(Vec(4,SInt(16.W)))
      val Out = Output(Vec(4,SInt(16.W)))
    }
  )
  /*
   ...
  */
}
```

What would be the best way to `poke` the `io.In` vector? I understand you can always do a loop to poke each element of `io.In` individually. Is there any better way to do this? I tried `poke(...io.In.toBits,/*some BigInt*/)`. It didn't seem to work.

Same question for using `expect` on the `io.Out` vector.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question will be the as yet unimplemented Vector literals. These are very likely to be be part of a release for Summer 2020.
See [Vec literals Chisel3 Issue #849](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/issues/849). In the meantime writing some helper methods to poke the elements individually is probably your best bet.